# Why does Click Event trigger Function in Firefox, but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, event-listener

I'm dynamically creating `<option>` elements with a `click` event attached to and append them to the corresponding `<select>` element. With Firefox the function that handles the event is triggered, but with Chrome not. 
Why is there a difference? What should I add or change?

I can't say I tried something, besides looking for answers on the web. I have no clue what is going on. Below is the function that should change the properties of the element.

```
function change_display () {
  let display_content = this.textContent.match(/[0-9]/g).join('') + ":00"
  this.className === "arthur" ? arthur_display.textContent = display_content
                              : johnny_display.textContent = display_content;
}
//
Some code
//
new_option.addEventListener('click', change_display);
```

I expect the content of the referred element to change when the event is triggered. But nothing is happening - not even an error.
If I should edit my question with more information, please let me know.

Comment: it would be kind of helpful to see the code where the click handler is assigned...

Comment: I think the problem might be with the callback function here. The click event trigger definetly works in Chrome. You can try this out https://codepen.io/ionut_the/pen/yWBQWj its taken straight from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thank you. But why should that matter to Chrome and not to Firefox, if there is a problem with the callback function?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm seeing a simliar situation.